# How to build a query that gets its values from a file

Tags: oracle, query, oracle-sql-developer

I'm trying to build a query that uses the values in a file

`select Epm,Emp_num,Emp_Addr From Dir_Rimco_Table where Emp in (Dir_Emp_Rsed.txt)`

Constraints

-I can't create a new table

-I can't modify Dir_Rimco_Table

-Current Privileges

[image]

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: You can't expect the database server to guess that you want it to read some file; you must read the file somehow and present its contents in the query following the right syntax. May be you can use [an external table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm)

Comment: unfortunately I can't create a table

Comment: What about using a temp table? It will only exist for the duration of the query.

Comment: sure could you show me how to? and also, do you think I can do that with my current privileges?

Answer (score 0):

If the restriction on creating tables includes "external tables", then you need to get management to lift that restriction.  As stated, you can't expect oracle (or any rdbms product, for that matter) to just magically be able to recognize some external file as a data source and be able to process it with SQL statements.  External tables is *how* oracle does that.  If you read up on external tables in the oracle docs, you will see that it is not a table that contains data within the database, but simply a description of an external file, and that allows oracle to treat that file as if it were an actual table.